# How to control a div that covers all screen with Capybara Selenium

Tags: selenium, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec3

I Use Rails 5 Rspec with Capybara-Selenium, and I have an effect where during 1/2 second the screen is cover with a white div, and with jQuery-animate fades out and then appears the fields and other elements.

I have a lot of expectations like

`expect(page).to have_css("h3",text:"We have sent an email...")`

And now I have an error in javascript that causes than this div does not fade out, so the screen is all white, and **I would like that these expectation fails, but they don't fail**, the expectation pass even thought all screen is white

Can I control this white screen without adding en every scenario something like `expect(page).not_to have_selector("div_than_cover_the_screen")` ?

something like a "real_visible" option...: `expect(page).to have_css("h3",text:"We have sent an email...", real_visible: true)`

Comment: What do you mean by "control this white screen?" -  If you just want to test that the white screen disappears then you would do something like `expect(page).not_to have_css("#the_id_of_the_white_overlay_div")`

Comment: Yes, of course, this is a solution, but I was wondering if exist any kind of configuration that controls when a `expect(page).to have_css(...` can control if the element is "real visible"  or has something than covers it

Comment: I will edit my question

Comment: What is considered "visible" is controlled by the drivers, and there is no options you can pass to `have_css` to change it.   However, attempting to call `#click` on the element does a hit test in most drivers which would then raise an exception if the element wasn't actually interactable.

Comment: Although, unless you have completely different JS being loaded by every page, just adding one test that the overlay goes away on a page would probably be enough rather than adding the expectation to every scenario

Comment: Thanks, do you mean to override the click method of capybara?...mm well this div is in index page, after clics, redirects,.. maybe better just to create a method helper and call it from every where is needed,

Comment: You do't need to override the click method... just use it. eg `click_on("We have sent an email...")` will raise an exception if the div is present... and won't if it is not visible. So maybe do `expect { click_on("We have sent an email...") }.not_to raise_exception` or similar?